# Simple Library Xml serialization without new instance of class

Tags: java, serialization, simple-framework

In my Java project I try to use Simple Library (http://simple.sourceforge.net) for XML serialization.
Now I need do serializing from xml into existing instance of my class. but this library always create new instance.
For example I have some object in memory:

```
TObj myObject = new TObj();
myObject.field1 = 999;
myObject.field2 = 777;
```

Then I receive from server xml of this TObj but only part of fields, such as:

```
 <TObj field1="100">
```

I want serialize this xml in *myObject* variable. and after that result should be:

```
myObject.field1 = 100;
myObject.field2 = 777;
```

But simple library always create new instance of TObj class.
How I can achieve the desired???

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into using JAXB? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html

Answer (score 3):

Use the `read()` method on `Serializer` that accepts an instance of your class instead of the .class.

[http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/Serializer.html#read(T, java.io.File)](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/Serializer.html#read%28T,%20java.io.File%29)

Comment: Thanks it is woks. But may be you know how achieve the same behavior for fileds of object. for example the fields of my object is my classes and simple create new instance of them... sorry for my bad english:)

Answer (score 0):

maybe your TObj class doesn't follow simplexml's serialization & deserialization rules correctly.

I recommend you to use annotations to define your TObj so that simplexml will know how to serialize your object. Here is an example:

```
@Root(name = "Example")
public class SimpleExample {
    @Element(name = "Name", required = false)
    private String name;
}
```

By doing this, you can create a new instance of class SimpleExample and serialize it with the following method:

```
    public static <T> String marshal(T obj, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
    Strategy strategy = new AnnotationStrategy();
    Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy, format);
    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    serializer.write(obj, out);
    return out.toString();
}
```

You will get something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Example>
    <Name>value_of_this_field<Name>
<Example>
```